# isStartNewPage=true for a group is not working in jasper

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a jasper report where I have a table and have grouped its content based on a purchaserId. The grouping works fine but I also want the groups to be displayed on different pages. Following is my code snippet. This is how I have created sub-data set for table and have added a group in it.

```
<subDataset name="currentDuesDataSet">
        <field name="memberId" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
        <field name="purchaserId" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
        <group name="RECORDS_PER_PURCHASER" isStartNewPage="true">
            <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{purchaserId}]]></groupExpression>
        </group>
</subDataset>
```

and this is how I have attached the sub-data set to the table.

```
<jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">
<datasetRun subDataset="retroDuesDataSet"  >
    <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{retroDuesList})]]></dataSourceExpression>
</datasetRun>
<jr:column width="128"  >
<jr:groupHeader groupName="RECORDS_PER_PURCHASER">
    <jr:cell height="66" rowSpan="1">
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="0" y="49" width="128" height="15"  />
            <textElement>
                <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Member ID]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement mode="Transparent" x="0" y="2" width="128" height="15"  />
        <textElement verticalAlignment="Top" markup="html">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="12"/>
        </textElement>
        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["<B>Purchaser Id:" + $F{purchaserId} + "</B>"]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </jr:cell>
    </jr:groupHeader>
    <jr:columnHeader height="30" rowSpan="1">
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="128" height="30"  />
            <textElement>
                <font isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[]]></text>
        </staticText>
    </jr:columnHeader>
    <jr:detailCell height="38" rowSpan="1">
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
        <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="0" y="2" width="128" height="18" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"  />
        <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
            <font size="12"/>
        </textElement>
        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{memberId}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </jr:detailCell>
</jr:column>                    
</jr:table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `keepTogether` property of `<group>` should work for you such that `keepTogether` and `isStartNewPage` will makes group result together and starts new group from new page.

```
<group name="RECORDS_PER_PURCHASER" isStartNewPage="true" keepTogether="true">
     <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{purchaserId}]]></groupExpression>
</group>
```